# Batch modify HTML (in PHP files) using jQuery-like commands and Linux scripts

Tags: jquery, batch-processing

I have a collection of old PHP files that need to have their HTML modified to fit to a new design. Tasks include selecting particular elements, removing / adding classes, appending content and manipulating the positions of elements.

In true developer style I'd like to automate it. This is perfectly suited to jQuery or other JS libraries (in fact I've already written the code to act as a temporary hack).

Any suggestions on how to modify a specific file and then save the modified contents?

What do you think about loading jQuery with NodeJS?

Comment: I once looked for something similar, but for plain HTML files (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/79615/html-text-editor-with-dom-manipulation). However I can't imagine how it would work for PHP file, since they are seldom valid HTML files thus they wouldn't produce a usable DOM structure that you could manipulate with JS/jQuery. Actually this sounds like a job where you should be refactoring repeated design elements into separate templates instead.

Comment: Part of the automation process is actually going to be a refactoring.

PHP may in fact render as usable DOM element with some minor hacks - i.e. replace <?php with <php> and ?> with </php> before the processing and then return it afterwards (sed or some Perl regex on the command line would do the trick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be in need of a DOM Selector engine in PHP. Try this http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/, similar to jQuery supports CSS3 also.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it'll be very helpful. I'd vote up the answer but I don't have enough reputation points myself :(

Comment: You could agree with the solution. :)